# How to change screen with a popup widget in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm using a popup as a pause menu in my kivy app. But I can't figure out how to change screens with it. I tried root.manager.current but that didn't work since my popup widget isn't a screen. I also tried to create a function in python using self.manager.current but alas that did not work either. This is the only idea I can think of now but it doesn't work either. Any and all help is appreciated.

python snippet

```
class PausePopup(Popup):
    pass

class MahScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MahMenu(Screen):
    pass

class MahGame(Screen):

class MahGameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        window_color = get_color_from_hex("#eaeaea")
        Window.clearcolor = window_color
        return MahScreenManager()

MahGameApp().run()
```

kv

```
<MahScreenManager>:
    MahMenu:
        name: "menu"
        id: menu
    MahGame:
        name: "game"
        id: game 

<PausePopup>:
    title: "Gahme is paused"
    size_hint: .5, .7
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: 10
        spacing: 10
        Button:
            text: "Continue"
            on_release: root.dismiss()

        Button:
            text: "Settings"
            on_release: app.open_settings()
        Button:
            text: "Main Menu"
            on_release: Factory.MahGame().current = "menu"

<MahMenu>:
    BoxLayout:
        padding: 50
        spacing: 25
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            text: "Start Mah Gahme"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.manager.current = "game"
        Button:
            text: "Quit"
            on_release: app.stop()

<MahGame>:
    Button:
        text: "Pause"
        size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
        on_release: Factory.PausePopup().open()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your screenmanager in the `App` class forexample, you can do like this:

```python
app.sm.current = "menu"
```

Then in your App class, do like this:

```python
    self.sm = MahScreenManager()
    return self.sm
```

Comment: I don't it's as you can see in the python snippet :/

Comment: I added more code, hopefully that clears things up a bit! Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Thank you so much!